# UIToolbar Subclassing Doesn't work

Tags: ios, subclass, uitoolbar

I'm trying to subclass a UIToolbar but the code doesn't seem to be working when I add the class to a UIToolbar in Interface Builder. What am I doing wrong here? I'm also looking for adding UIBarbuttonitems etc., this is just a test eg., daniel

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //Customization//
        UIImage *ToolbarBackgroundImage;
        ToolbarBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DefaultNavBar"];

        [self setBackgroundImage:ToolbarBackgroundImage forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        [self setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionAny];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    //do nothing//
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a storyboard, you should also implement `initWithCoder:`.

When a storyboard is being loaded, a decoder is used to create objects defined in the storyboard. `initWithCoder:` comes from the `NSCoding` protocol, and is a way for classes to deserialize themselves from coders. You can read about it in detail [here](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

If you wish to support both nibs and storyboards, there is a method available you can implement in your views, `awakeFromNib`.

Comment: alright, but is that why the uitoolbar background image code doesn't get called though?

Comment: @DanielRanLehmann Hey, could you please elaborate on why that is the case? :O Why the image would work with `initWithCoder` and not in `initWithFrame`? and secondly, whats the difference between the two :S

Comment: @LeoNatan ok thank you for that, something I didnt know had to be done when working with story boards; and what of my second question?

Comment: One is a normal initialization of a view with a frame. The second is, as explained in the answer, initialization of an object from a coder.